# for loop to count syllables in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, count

Back with another question from the same project!
The project is for a first semester introduction to programming course (Java) and for the project we have to calculate the FRI for some example texts using only what we have learned up to this point.

My question is: How does someone compute syllables using a for loop. So far, I have it set up to go through each letter, check for vowels, stop when it sees a vowel and then check the next letter for another vowel or another character.

It works if I'm counting syllables in words with vowels and follow my first two rules.

However, I don't know how to count a single word without any vowels in it as a single syllable.

Here are the rules for counting syllables we have to follow:

> 3. The number of syllables contained in a word is based on the number of occurrences of vowels that is, the characters a, e, i, o, u with
>      the following modifications:
>
> a. Each group of adjacent vowels counts as one syllable. For example,
>   “real, air, sound, tooth, soap” are one-syllable words, the word
>   “regal” has two syllables, “continuous” has three and “queueing” just
>   one. The role of ‘y’ is ambiguous. It can be both a consonant (“year”,
>   “royal”, “yes”) and a vowel (“by”, “ugly”, “many”). We ignore the ‘y’
>   ambiguity and your program must take it for a consonant.
>
> b. An ‘-e’ or ‘-ed’ at the end of a word does not count as a syllable
>   For example, the word, "validate" has four vowels but only three
>   syllables. There are only few words where rule b eliminates actual
>   syllables (for instance ‘-ed’ after ‘t’ or ‘d’ is not silent), such
>   omissions do not significantly distort the test results. You should
>   also notice that words having double ‘e’ at the end do not lose a
>   syllable for their count. For instance, “committee” has three
>   syllables counted. The rule may also increase the counting, for
>   instance carefree has three syllables by the rule, but it sounds as
>   having two. There is an important case when b is overruled as
>   explained in the next section c.
>
> c. Each word has at least one syllable Even if a word does not contain
>   any vowel, or the previous rules give a count of zero, it is still
>   counted as having one syllable. For example, the words str, grrrr ,
>   pp, the, she, he, fed, led” all have one syllable

And here is the code I have so far:

```
// While loop to count words and increment syllable count per word
while(countWords.hasNext()){
    String word = countWords.useDelimiter(WORD_DELIMITERS).next();

    if(word.compareTo("") != 0){
        numWords++;

        for(k=0; k < word.length(); k++){
            char letter = word.charAt(k);

            if(letter == 'A' || letter == 'a' 
                || letter == 'I' || letter == 'i' 
                || letter == 'O' || letter == 'o' 
                || letter == 'U' || letter == 'u'){
                if(k+1 < word.length()){
                    char nextLetter = word.charAt(k+1);

                    if(nextLetter == 'A' || nextLetter == 'a' 
                        || nextLetter == 'E' || nextLetter == 'e' 
                        || nextLetter == 'I' || nextLetter == 'i' 
                        || nextLetter == 'O' || nextLetter == 'o' 
                        || nextLetter == 'U' || nextLetter =='u' 
                        || nextLetter == ' '){
                        numSyllables++;
                    }
                    else{
                        numSyllables++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(letter == 'E' || letter == 'e'){
                if(k+1 < word.length()){
                    char nextLetter = word.charAt(k+1);

                    if(nextLetter != 'D' || nextLetter != 'd' 
                        || nextLetter != 'A' || nextLetter != 'a' 
                        || nextLetter != 'I' || nextLetter != 'i' 
                        || nextLetter != 'O' || nextLetter != 'o' 
                        || nextLetter != 'U' || nextLetter !='u' 
                        || nextLetter == ' '){
                        numSyllables++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(numSyllables == 0){
            numSyllables = 1;
        }
        System.out.println((numWords) + " " + word + " " + numSyllables);
        numSyllables = 0;
    }
}
```

Example printout:

> 1 Hello 1  2 world 1 3 This 1  4 is 1  5 just 1  6 a 1  7 test 1  8 to
>   1  9 see 1  10 how 1  11 my 1  12 program 2  13 works 1  14 up 1  15
>   to 1  16 this 1  17 point 2  18 I'm 1  19 pretty 1  20 sure 1  21 I've
>   1  22 figured 3  23 out 2  24 the 1  25 syllable 1  26 thing 1  27 but
>   1  28 I'm 1  29 not 1  30 sure 1

Comment: Aside, because I'm just nitpicking the requirements of your assignment: "continuous" has four syllables, at least for a British English speaker (con tin you us). Also, these rules don't work for US English, where "squirrelled" only has one syllable (but two in British English); but these rules say it has two.

Comment: XD yeah, my husband nit-picked that too.

From the project requirements: ""Note that the rules of counting syllables as described above is not 100% accurate for
spoken English. Some additional refinement of the rules were omitted for sake of
simplicity of the selection logic in the program.""

Comment: Can you give some example of words with the expected outcome and your counts? By the way, this exercise sounds pretty interesting for non-native English speakers ^^. I see three faulty points: **1.**: in your `if ...else...` clause, you're doing the same thing. Then, your `if...else...` is irrelevant :) you should have different outcome depending on the condition. **2.** if vowel is *e*, you don't check `if next letter is a vowel` (like `a`). **3.**, you don't consider the last letter: example: *Mommy* (or mummy...)

Comment: Made updates to the original post to show new code and outcomes (with examples).

Comment: @AndyTurner How many syllables is "vacuum"?

Comment: @shmosel depends how much I've had to drink.

Comment: @shmosel sorry for question-unrelated comment, but if sober, how many syllable is it supposed to have? [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vacuum) says 2 if I can still read phonetics...

Comment: @Al1 Well, how many syllables does "continuum" have?

Comment: @shmosel I'm speechless: according to the dictionary and regardless US or UK English, it counts 4 this time.

Answer (score 4):

## Comment on your code

Here are few comments on the code you posted:

1. String equality vs String sorting

   ```
   word.compareTo("") != 0
   ```

   is a bit strange. `compareTo` is usually done for alphabetical purpose. Maybe you wanted to use `!word.equals("")`
2. redundant `if...else...`

   ```
   if(nextLetter == 'A' || nextLetter == 'a' 
       || nextLetter == 'E' || nextLetter == 'e'
       || nextLetter == 'I' || nextLetter == 'i'
       || nextLetter == 'O' || nextLetter == 'o'
       || nextLetter == 'U' || nextLetter =='u'
       || nextLetter == ' '){
       numSyllables++;
   }
   else{
       numSyllables++;
   }
   ```

   So if the condition is `true` **or** `false`, you'll end up with `numSyllables++` so there is no point to have the condition ... Moreover, `nextLetter == ' '` may never happen if you only have space-free words
3. Final "a", "i", "u", "o" are ignored:

   ```
   if (letter == 'A' ...){
       if(k+1 < word.length()){
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   It means if `k == word.length() - 1`, you do nothing. In the word `Vienna`, you'll ignore the last "a". You did the same thing for the letter "e" which is correct as last "e" has to be ignored
4. Tests never happens + final "ed"/"eD" not ignored

   ```
   if(nextLetter != 'D' || nextLetter != 'd' 
       || nextLetter != 'A' || nextLetter != 'a' 
       || nextLetter != 'I' || nextLetter != 'i' 
       || nextLetter != 'O' || nextLetter != 'o' 
       || nextLetter != 'U' || nextLetter !='u' 
       || nextLetter == ' '){
       numSyllables++;
   }
   ```

   if `nextLetter` is `D or d`: it is `D`, then `nextLetter != 'd'` is true, otherwise, `nextLetter != 'D'` would have already been `true` so the next tests will never happen. Plus, you do not ignored final "ed" here because if it is `eD`, `nextLetter != 'd'` is true, and if it is `ed` then `nextLetter != 'D'` is true
5. You don't seem to skip consecutive vowel

## Count with loop

My suggestion is to have two dedicated methods, for readibility purpose:

1. a method to check if a letter is a vowel or not
2. a method to count the number of syllable

The method to check is a letter is a vowel or not is obviously case-insensitive:

```
private static boolean isVowel(char letter) {
    return letter == 'A' || letter == 'a'
            || letter == 'E' || letter == 'e'
            || letter == 'O' || letter == 'o'
            || letter == 'I' || letter == 'i'
            || letter == 'U' || letter == 'u';
}
```

Then the method to count the number of syllable given a word has some modification compared to yours:

1. I'm using a **while loop**: because you need to skip consecutive vowel, a "pointer" will be using and navigate through the word
2. I'll first **check if a letter is a vowel** or not:

   2.1 *It is not a vowel*: syllable count does not increase and the pointer moves forward

   2.2 *The vowel is not an "E"*: syllable count increase by 1 and the pointer moves until the next non-vowel letter

   2.3 *The vowel is an E*: check if the "e" is the last letter or if it is the one before last followed by a "d": in this case, follow the rule 2.1, otherwise, follow the rule 2.2
3. **Count return is compared with 1**: by using `Math.max(count, 1)`, I'm ensuring that at least `1` is returned

The code is:

```
private static int countWithLoop(String word) {
    // start counting
    int syllableCount = 0;

    // use a while loop
    int index = 0;
    while (index < word.length()) {
        char letter = word.charAt(index);

        // if vowel:
        if (isVowel(letter)) {
            // specific case of "E"/"e"
            if (letter == 'E' || letter == 'e') {

                // 1. last "e" is ignored:
                if (index == word.length() - 1) {
                    index++;
                }
                // 2. if "ed" finished the word, it is ignored
                else if (index == word.length() - 2
                        && (word.charAt(word.length() - 1) == 'd' || word.charAt(word.length() - 1) == 'D')) {
                    index++;
                }
                // 3. this is neither a last "e" or last "ed". Count as a syllable
                else {
                    // count one more syllable...
                    syllableCount++;
                    // ...and skip consecutive vowel
                    while (isVowel(letter) && index < word.length() - 1) {
                        index++;
                        letter = word.charAt(index);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // count one more syllable...
                syllableCount++;
                // ...and skip consecutive vowel
                while (isVowel(letter) && index < word.length() - 1) {
                    index++;
                    letter = word.charAt(index);
                }
            }
        }
        // otherwise, keep going
        else {
            index++;
        }
    }

    // return
    return Math.max(1, syllableCount);
}
```

## Count with Regex

Another solution, a bit more complex but also a bit funnier, is to use Regular Express, known as Regex. It basically requires a pattern and the pattern will be tested against a `String`. If the pattern is found, the matching characters are returned and the pattern will be tested against the remaining characters until nothing is found. This will use [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes

The code looks like

```
private static int countWithRegex(String word) {
    String i = "(?i)[aiou][aeiou]*|e[aeiou]*(?!d?\\b)";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(i).matcher(word);
    int count = 0;

    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
    }

    // return at least 1
    return Math.max(count, 1);
}
```

Some explanation about `i`:

```
(?i)[aiou][aeiou]*|e[aeiou]*(?!d?\\b)   = complete regex
(?i)                                    = case insensitivity: A=a, B=b and so on
    [aiou]                              = look for letter "a", "i", "o", "u", and their 
                                           capital letter counterpart
                 *                      = look for the characters between the bracket 
                                          with zero, one or more occurences
    [aiou][aeiou]*                      = look for non-E vowel followed a zero, one 
                                          or more vowel. Like "a", or "Oa", or "ueu"
                  |                     = Or ...
                   e                    = simple look for letter "e" or "E"
                    [aeiou]*            = same as above: look for "e" followed by 
                                          consecutive vowels
                            (?!.....)   = but exclude "e"/"E" when followed by...
                               d?\\b    = ...an optional "d"/"D" letter and \\b refer 
                                          to the end of the String: it excludes final
                                          "e" and final "ed"
```

## Main

And here is the main:

```
public static void main(String... aArgs) {

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    words.add("real");
    words.add("air");
    words.add("sound");
    words.add("tooth");
    words.add("soap");
    words.add("regal");
    words.add("continuous");
    words.add("queueing");
    words.add("committee");
    words.add("carefree");
    words.add("grrrr");
    words.add("she");
    words.add("fed");
    // Challenge the "ed" but not at the end of the word
    words.add("Medecine");
    // Challenge a final "e"
    words.add("Stone");
    // Challenge a final "ed"
    words.add("Stoned");
    // Challenge a double vowel
    words.add("Year");
    // Challenge case sensitivity
    words.add("BoAr");
    // Expected answer depends on the number of drink Andy has taken
    words.add("Vacuum");

    System.out.println("----Counting with Loop----");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " " + words.get(i) + " " + countWithLoop(words.get(i)));
    }
    System.out.println("----Counting with Regex----");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " " + words.get(i) + " " + countWithRegex(words.get(i)));
    }
}
```

With the followed output:

```
----Counting with Loop----
0 real 1
1 air 1
2 sound 1
3 tooth 1
4 soap 1
5 regal 2
6 continuous 3
7 queueing 1
8 committee 3
9 carefree 3
10 grrrr 1
11 she 1
12 fed 1
13 Medecine 3
14 Stone 1
15 Stoned 1
16 Year 1
17 BoAr 1
18 Vacuum 2
----Counting with Regex----
0 real 1
1 air 1
2 sound 1
3 tooth 1
4 soap 1
5 regal 2
6 continuous 3
7 queueing 1
8 committee 3
9 carefree 3
10 grrrr 1
11 she 1
12 fed 1
13 Medecine 3
14 Stone 1
15 Stoned 1
16 Year 1
17 BoAr 1
18 Vacuum 2
```

Comment: Thanks so much for giving me so much feedback! Sadly, I'm not allowed to use methods (not there yet) or anything else outside of loops. (We're only in chapter 4 of the text book right now, and can only use what we've learned up to this point.)

I was able to get it to work though, just had to go back and mess with things for hours.

All good now, thank you!

Comment: I see... Well, my answer may be be useful later :) To mark this question closed, maybe you could post a self-answer (post an answer and hit the green mark) to highlight what was wrong. Anyway, please watch out your `if...else...` syntax and if you can't use methods, I can't encourage enough using comments to organise your code

Comment: countWithLoop code hangs with word tornado, but regex works.